# Is the Given Languages CFL or DCFL?

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

$L_1$ = {$a^nb^mc^xd^y$|$n=m$ or $x=y$}

$L_2$ = {$a^nb^xc^md^y$|$n=m$ or $x=y$}

For $L_1$:

- Push a's
- Now pop the same number of b's , Given n=m
- If Stack is empty and x=y=0 accept the Langauge
- else push c's and pop d's
- If Stack is empty accept the Langauge

It's DCFL and also CFL.

For the $L_2$: It's Not CFL.

But the answer key mentioned in my Quiz said that they both are CFL.

[Answer_key](https://imgur.com/a/EgZUKwt)

How $L_2$ is CFL and the $L_1$ not DCFL?

Answer (score 1):

Your argument for $L_1$ isn't quite correct, but the core idea can indeed be adapted to obtain a deterministic pushdown automaton for $L_1$. I don't know why the answer key claims that the language is non deterministic context-free; that is probably something to take up with whoever provided that key.

For the second language, there is a pushdown automaton for it, thus it is indeed context-free. The automaton guesses first whether to check $n = m$ or $x = y$, and then does that.

Comment: Can you explain more about the second language and how it's CFL, if i push a's , push b's then I need to pop c's but c has power of m not y so i don't reach to a solution here, if i push a's pop b's than I lost the count for the c and d.

Comment: @VedantKhandelwal You only check one of them, based on the first non-deterministic choice.